# A non-numeric value encountered Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have a working function, but suddenly it now prompts an error.

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'A non-numeric value encountered',
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\fdis-laravel\app\Receivable.php', 67,
>   array('receivable_payment_head_id' => null, 'total_receivable' =>
>   '936.341')) in Receivable.php line 67

Here's my code using DB:Raw.

```php
<?php

public static function updateLessPaymentHead($receivable_payment_head_id, $total_receivable)
{
    $payment_head = DB::table('receivables_payment_head')
        ->where('id', $receivable_payment_head_id)
        ->update(
            ['total_receivables' => DB::raw('total_receivables' - $total_receivable),
                'total_payment' => DB::raw('total_payment' - $total_receivable),
            ]);

    return $payment_head;
}
```

Is there a way that I can address the non-numeric issue with DB:raw or do I need to first convert this to numeric before updating? I'm using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.1.

Comment: what do u trying to do here `'total_receivables' - $total_receivable` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your DB::raw.

`DB::raw('total_receivables' - $total_receivable)` will essentially try to subtract the value of `$total_receivable` from string `total_receivables`. However, I believe you need to subtract it from the value of column `total_receivable`. Then you need to change it to :

`DB::raw('total_receivables  - ' . $total_receivable )`

Please check updated code :

```
<?php 


public static function updateLessPaymentHead($receivable_payment_head_id, $total_receivable)
{
    if(!is_numeric($receivable_payment_head_id) || !is_numeric($total_receivable)){

        return [];
    }

    $payment_head = DB::table('receivables_payment_head')
        ->where('id', $receivable_payment_head_id)
        ->update(
            [
                'total_receivables' => DB::raw('total_receivables  - ' . $total_receivable ),
                'total_payment' => DB::raw('total_payment - ' . $total_receivable),
            ]);

    return $payment_head;
}
```

Comment: Thannk you for this !!! it works !!! I've got a null variable that is why!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code here: `'total_receivables' - $total_receivable` and here: `'total_payment' - $total_receivable` you are trying to subtract a number from a string, this is a php 7.1 error.

You have to get `total_receivables` and `total_receivables` separately and subtract then update the table.

Answer (score -1):

> You need to convert that in numeric format for that you can define
>   function parameter datatype like this

```
public static function updateLessPaymentHead(int $receivable_payment_head_id, int $total_receivable) 
    {
        $payment_head = DB::table('receivables_payment_head')
            ->where('id', $receivable_payment_head_id)
            ->update(
                ['total_receivables' => DB::raw('total_receivables' - $total_receivable),
                    'total_payment' => DB::raw('total_payment' - $total_receivable),
                ]);

        return $payment_head;
}
```

Comment: this is nothing to do with parameters data type, hes tying subtract  a number from a string